# jQuery Masonry append items without "growing" animation

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-masonry

I'm using Masonry and appending some items ($boxes is a bunch of HTML containing divs)

```
$('#masons').append($boxes).masonry('appended', $boxes, false);
```

This works -> the new divs are organized by Masonry properly. However, it includes an annoying animation where the box "grows" from the center of its position. I don't want this animation. How can I get rid of it?

I've tried

```
$('#masons').append($boxes).masonry('reload');
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all -> the new divs are not organized by Masonry.

Comment: If I do `$('#masons').append($boxes).masonry('reloadItems').masonry()`, this gets rid of the "growing" animation, but instead it appears that every div starts in the top left corner and is moved into position, instead of starting in position immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree. I'm not a great fan of the standard animation when appending new items, rather than using 'transitionDuration: 0' I find it neater to use the hiddenStyle option.

Masonry defaults to using:

```
hiddenStyle: {
  opacity: 0,
  transform: 'scale(0.001)'
}
```

You can pass your own version during initialisation, here I'm removing the scale option which will disable the "growing" animation.

```
  // Initialize Masonry
  $('#container').masonry
    itemSelector: ".item",
    hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the solution here: 
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/183

I had to set `transitionDuration: 0`

So the full code is...

```
// Initialize Masonry
$('#masons').masonry({
  columnWidth: 127.5,
  itemSelector: '.mason-block',
  transitionDuration: 0
});

// Generate boxes and then append them
$('#masons').append($boxes).masonry('appended', $boxes, true);

// Custom fading animation
$('.mason-block img').on('load', function() {
  $(this).fadeIn(250);
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) {
    $(this).load();
  }
});
```

Now they fade in nicely instead of "growing"